# Opera 10.51 Dragonfly not showing POST data

Tags: opera, opera-10

Does anyone know if there is a setting that will show me the POST requests in Dragonfly? I only see GET requests and the responses.

I am used to Firebug so wondering if this functionality is available.

Thanks.

Comment: You should already be able to see the POST requests in Dragonfly if you can see the GET requests.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Opera Dev forums](http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/398891) it appears you cannot:

> Currently it is only possible to get the head of a HTTP request, and not the body. We have a task for adding support for retrieving the body, but that has to be implemented in Scope first (the browser component that allows DFL to inspect the page).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com), a client side web proxy which (among hosts of other features) shows post data as plain text. It works with all major browsers and supports https. For more info refer to the web address given... seriously, it's an extremely valuable tool especially for debugging arcane errors in web apps accessed through IE and Opera.